# Copy file from on-prem sharepoint document library to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepointdocumentlibrary, data-gateway

I am trying to copy on-prem sharepoint files from a document library to sharepoint online document library using data gateway and power automate. I have tried using different methods but I either end up with corrupted files or the "file identifier" field doesn't have the correct value. I have been googling but many others have experienced the same issue. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.
Similar issues with no solution
[Issue1](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Copy-file-on-prem-to-SharePoint/td-p/1224201)
[Issue2](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Get-files-properties-on-premises-not-giving-identifier/td-p/177029)
[Issue3](https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/idea/e79c11dd-65a0-4988-a67f-d9bd7dc42e67)
[Issue4](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Getting-file-identifier-SharePoint-using-on-premise-gateway/td-p/1526413)

[Power automate to copy from on-prem to sharepoint online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onBIH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the official migration tool [SPMT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool). It can copy the contents of SharePoint server to SharePoint online.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Amy, This tool works like sharegate but I was confused why Data Gateway doesn't work as advertised.